# Getting started with JeroMQ in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, zeromq, jeromq

I am trying to use JeroMQ from MATLAB,
by implementing this example ( [How to use jeromq in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060320/how-to-use-jeromq-in-matlab) ):

```
% Author : Dheepak Krishnamurthy
% License : BSD 3 Clause

import org.zeromq.ZMQ;

ctx = zmq.Ctx();

socket = ctx.createSocket(ZMQ.REP);

socket.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:7575');

message = socket.recv(0);

json_data = native2unicode(message.data)';

message = zmq.Msg(8);
message.put(unicode2native('Received'));

socket.send(message, 0);
socket.close()
```

The script runs until line:

> `message = socket.recv(0);`

but stucks there.

MATLAB would then not respond anymore and has to be killed with Task Manager.

Can someone give a hint, if there are additional things to do, in order to get this running?

Answer (score 4):

### `JeroMQ` call signatures state:

```
        /**
         * Receive a message.
         *
         * @return the message received, as an array of bytes; null on error.
         */
        public final byte[] recv()
        {
            return recv(0);
        }

        /**
         * Receive a message.
         *
         * @param flags
         *            the flags to apply to the receive operation.
         * @return the message received, as an array of bytes; null on error.
         */
        public final byte[] recv(int flags)
        {
            zmq.Msg msg = base.recv(flags);

            if (msg != null) {
                return msg.data();
            }

            mayRaise();
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Receive a message in to a specified buffer.
         *
         * @param buffer
         *            byte[] to copy zmq message payload in to.
         * @param offset
         *            offset in buffer to write data
         * @param len
         *            max bytes to write to buffer.
         *            If len is smaller than the incoming message size,
         *            the message will be truncated.
         * @param flags
         *            the flags to apply to the receive operation.
         * @return the number of bytes read, -1 on error
         */
        public final int recv(byte[] buffer, int offset, int len, int flags)
        {
            zmq.Msg msg = base.recv(flags);

            if (msg != null) {
                return msg.getBytes(0, buffer, offset, len);
            }

            return -1;
        }
```

### Your code uses the 2nd one:
`public final byte[] recv( int flags ){...}`

for which your code injects a hardcoded integer value of **`0`** for the **`flags`** parameter.

### Next,
 the **`int flags`** *meaning* is better documented in API as:

> The ***flags*** argument is a combination of the flags defined below:
>   **`ZMQ_NOBLOCK`**
>   Specifies that the operation should be performed in non-blocking mode. If there are no messages available on the specified socket, the **`zmq_recv()`** function shall fail with **`errno`** set to **`EAGAIN`**.

With due care, one may use **`DONTWAIT`** flag inside `JeroMQ`, but some other meaningful options are hard to find from bottom up.

### So finally,
 let's read the ZeroMQ defined
and recognised set of ***flags***:

```
// ------------------------------------------------- // Socket options.                                                           
#define ZMQ_HWM                1
#define ZMQ_SWAP               3
#define ZMQ_AFFINITY           4
#define ZMQ_IDENTITY           5
#define ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE          6
#define ZMQ_UNSUBSCRIBE        7
#define ZMQ_RATE               8
#define ZMQ_RECOVERY_IVL       9
#define ZMQ_MCAST_LOOP        10
#define ZMQ_SNDBUF            11
#define ZMQ_RCVBUF            12
#define ZMQ_RCVMORE           13
#define ZMQ_FD                14
#define ZMQ_EVENTS            15
#define ZMQ_TYPE              16
#define ZMQ_LINGER            17
#define ZMQ_RECONNECT_IVL     18
#define ZMQ_BACKLOG           19
#define ZMQ_RECOVERY_IVL_MSEC 20   /*  opt. recovery time, reconcile in 3.x   */
#define ZMQ_RECONNECT_IVL_MAX 21

// ------------------------------------------------- // Send/recv options.                                                        
#define ZMQ_NOBLOCK 1    // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<- THIS ONE IS NEEDED
#define ZMQ_SNDMORE 2

// ------------------------------------------------- // I/O Multplexing options.
#define ZMQ_POLLIN  1
#define ZMQ_POLLOUT 2
#define ZMQ_POLLERR 4

// ------------------------------------------------- // Device types.
#define ZMQ_STREAMER  1
#define ZMQ_FORWARDER 2
#define ZMQ_QUEUE     3
```

### EPILOGUE:

If using `.recv( 0 )` your code **will BLOCK**, until the `socket`-instance indeed receives anything `.recv()`-able in the local-side from any, possibly existing in some near or farther future, compatible, `.connect()`-ed remote end ( a **`REQ`** socket et al ).

If using `.recv( 1 )` your code **will NOT BLOCK**, but one should properly handle both possible return-states **`{ <msg.data()_Value> | (EXC, NULL) }`** and consult with ZeroMQ **`errno`** details, to act in accord with the signalled situation context.

Comment: ★★★★☆ -- Good answer. The **Epilogue** in particular was very moving. 8/10. Would recommend.

Comment: [ a *mandatory* piece of cake for you, Tasos ] Glad you have enjoyed the story. Going into heterogeneous distributed systems is a thrilling experience for even seasoned hackers. It is not easy to guess and fit the level-of-detail and the long vertical stacks may wreck havoc in so many places... Sometimes the longer way around the issue helps more, than a straightforward, but short-sighted notice about a root cause in using rather `NOBLOCK` instead of omnipotent meaning of `0`.

Comment: hahahah, I wholeheartedly agree! I just found the word **epilogue** a bit funny; it gives the whole answer a rather sombre, literary tone :p  "Thus became of our heroes ... join us again next week, for more daring adventures in distributed systems design!" \o/