# JeroMQ subscriber connection breaks when recv-ing in Matlab

Tags: matlab, zeromq, jeromq

Using JeroMQ in Matlab, my subscriber connection drops when I try to `recv` a message. I have verified this with Wireshark. I also note that the closing of the TCP connection is initiated by my subscribing port, not the publishing port.

```
javaclasspath('jeromq-0.5.1.jar')
import org.zeromq.*;

ctx = zmq.Ctx();
socket = ctx.createSocket(ZMQ.SUB);
socket.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:5996')
message = socket.recv(1) %this is when the connection gets dropped
```

[Wireshark screenshot showing connection being closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJ9ha.png)

I don't know for sure if it would help, but I have investigated using this,

```
socket.setSocketOpt(ZMQ.ZMQ_TCP_KEEPALIVE,1)
```

but Matlab reports that ZMQ_TCP_KEEPALIVE is an unrecognized function or variable.

I am indebted to the folks on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060320/how-to-use-jeromq-in-matlab/44865494#44865494) thread for getting me started on the right foot with JeroMQ in Matlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more research and factored in suggestions from some friends over at [Github](https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq/issues/756). Turns out that my socket wasn't closing until later in the code at my `close()` function. Here is my working code for others looking to get started using JeroMQ in Matlab. Seems that some of the code on other posts is antiquated.

```
javaclasspath('jeromq-0.5.1.jar')
import org.zeromq.*;

%subscribe to ZMQ feed
context = ZContext();
socket = context.createSocket(ZMQ.SUB); 
success = false;
while(~success)
    success = socket.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:5996');
end
socket.subscribe("");
socket.setTCPKeepAlive(1);

%receive a message
message = socket.recv(0); %nonblocking receive uses argument (1)

%when done
socket.close();
```